# drupal not loading js/css files in default/files/

Tags: apache, drupal, drupal-7

My drupal site isn't loading JS files nor CSS files located

```
sites/default/files/js
```

OR

```
sites/default/files/css
```

even though they are there I can see them on FTP, their permissions are 664 and I can't change them they keep going back to 664. other files in sites/default/ are being loaded but not those.

Locally the site is working fine so I know it's a server issue! any suggestions?

Comment: Try a change a file permission 664 to 644

Comment: @Mehul, I just tried, it got back to 664, I am unable to change it for some reason!

Comment: Have you clear the cache ?

Comment: @Rupesh yes I tried :(

Comment: I have to say one thing, I think it's apache safe mod issue, one problem was it's not loading jquery.cookie.js until I had to rename it to jquery_cookie.js then it started working, right now JS files in sites/default/files/js  throw a 404 not found...

Comment: what is permission of `css` and `js` folders?

Comment: Have a look at this topic : http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/20364/weird-permissions-problems-for-sites-default-files

Hope it will help!

Comment: Is your hosting provider using Plesk server? Because it could cause that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your theme to make sure the css and js files are there? The info file?

Comment: I actually see the 404 in the firebug console, I mean the browser tried to connect but didn't get the file

Answer (score 1):

Make sure folders (`sites/default/files/js` and `sites/default/files/css`) permission is `755` or `744`
it's important to `User` have executable permission to this folders

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is not advisable to keep your JS & CSS files in `sites/default` folder. They should be kept in the `sites/all/theme` or `sites/all/modules` directory.

And, even then it is not necessary that they will be loaded on your website. You must specify it if you want to load these file on your site. This is how it is done:

**For Theme:**

> add `scripts[] = mytheme.js` in the theme.info file to add js
>
> add `stylesheets[all][] = mytheme.css` in the theme.info file to add css

**For Module:**

> use `drupal_add_js('path_to_file')` to add js file
>
> use `drupal_add_css('path_to_file')` to add css file

Considering that for *some* reason you have put the files in `sites/default` folder, you will need to provide the read permissions to the files. Its advisable to set them to `755`.

Comment: Those files are there after checking compress JS and CSS in admin performance page. They are included to the browser because, I commented up earlier that:
I actually see the 404 in the firebug console, I mean the browser tried to connect but didn't get the file.

I will try to move them even though Drupal put them there and loads them automatically...

Answer (score 1):

The first question is, how do you include those css & Js to your site? using a module or from a theme?
In all cases, you should put them either in the module directory or in the theme directory. 
If you put them in the theme directory, you should add those files to your .info file of the theme. This is the best way to include CSS/JS files to a theme.

Comment: Those files are there after checking compress JS and CSS in admin performance page. They are included to the browser because, I commented up earlier that:
I actually see the 404 in the firebug console, I mean the browser tried to connect but didn't get the file.

I will try to move them even though Drupal put them there and loads them automatically...

Answer (score 0):

**For clarity's sake**

- 404 means the server could not locate the resource (file in this case).
- If you file permissions are 664, and it's parent folders are also 664, then anyone can read the file so this seems like a non issue.

@kellyjohnson is asking if the files exist, because of what the 404 error means conceptually. He seems to understand that you are observing the 404 in your browser console.  That is agreed upon.  But the natural question then is do the files physically exists where you expect them to be. If you can verify that files exist then there are only a couple options left to explore.

**Cases**

1. In the case of public assets (assets under the application's document root), it's likely the server's document root is not what you believe it to be; in other words the absolute path to the files for which the server is attempting to server is not the same path to the physical location of your files.

   a) Debug this issue by determining your configured document root, which will likely be the base path of the main "index.php" application entry point.  From there trace your relative path to your assets.  If you still believe all is correct then the remaining option would be that the web server is rewriting your requests for assets, and that is where your attention should focus.
2. In the case of non public assets (assets outside of the document root) it's likely your application routing is not routing to the directory you are assuming it should route to.

   b) this case is arguably the easier to debug, because you will enter the application which at any point you can echo debugging code, and trace the execution to the asset provider.

Good Luck.